# Nuget Package Manager Error 'Illegal characters in path.'

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I use Visual Studio 2017 and my NuGet Package Manager doesn't work consistently.
I open 2 projects for test this problem with sames properties and same names (Wpfappt, wpfapph) in wpfappt the manager works, but in wpfapph it doesn't.

This is the messages in the output field:
wpfappt (it works):

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfAppt\WpfAppt\WpfAppt.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.office.interop.excel/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.office.interop.excel/index.json 822ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.office.interop.excel/15.0.4795.1000/microsoft.office.interop.excel.15.0.4795.1000.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.office.interop.excel/15.0.4795.1000/microsoft.office.interop.excel.15.0.4795.1000.nupkg 185ms
Installing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4795.1000.
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfAppt\WpfAppt\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 3.62 sec for C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfAppt\WpfAppt\WpfAppt.csproj.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4795.1000' to WpfAppt
Executing nuget actions took 3.54 sec
Time Elapsed: 00:00:10.3848087
========== Finished ==========
```

And this is the message from the other project:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' with respect to project 'WpfApph', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 754.28 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3'
Resolved actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3'
Retrieving package 'Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3' from 'nuget.org'.
Adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' to folder 'C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfApph\packages'
Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' to folder 'C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfApph\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' does not exist in project 'WpfApph'
Removing package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' from folder 'C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfApph\packages'
**Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' from folder** 'C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfApph\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 1.1 sec
**An error occurred while writing file** 'C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfApph\WpfApph\packages.config': Failed to write packages.config as XML file 'C:\Users\Yogev\source\repos\WpfApph\WpfApph\packages.config'. Error: 'Illegal characters in path.'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.8665589
========== Finished ==========
```

Thank you.

Comment: it's possible each one is using it's own nuget.exe client... can you see anything else in the logs that indicate what the client version is of each one?  Also look for the full nuget install command and check all the parameters being passed.